# How to write rewriteCondition "is a file" Using request_uri and rewriteBase

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need find out if a request_uri do not point to a file in a specific directory, using RewriteBase.

I.e. URL is

```
http://localhost/~username/projectname/images/logo.gif
```

File is in directory

```
/home/username/public_html/projectname/www/images/logo.gif
```

.htacces should be something like this:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /~username/projectname/

RewriteCondition /home/username/public_html/projectname/www%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) app/file-not-found.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Unfortunately, the RewriteCondition is interpreted as

```
/home/username/public_html/projectname/www/~username/projectname/images/logo.gif
```

and not as

```
/home/username/public_html/projectname/www/images/logo.gif
```

therefore the condition is always true :(
How to write the .htaccess correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteBase is used only on RewriteRule, not in REQUEST_URI.

I haven't test it but you could use a condition like this:

```
RewriteCondition %{REQUEST_URI} ^/~username/projectname/(.*)$
RewriteCondition /home/username/public_html/projectname/www/%1 -f
```

Or, if `projectname` and `username` can change:

```
RewriteCondition %{REQUEST_URI} ^/~([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)$
RewriteCondition /home/%1/public_html/%2/www/%3 -f
```

Then you can make the RewriteRule as you want.

```
RewriteRule ^/~([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)$ /home/$1/public_html/$2/www/$3 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/file-not-found.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

**Do not specify any RewriteBase with the code above**